# KMM: Build fails caused by being locked by another Gradle instance, when switching the OS to build

Tags: gradle, kotlin-multiplatform-mobile

I created a KMM project (ios framework distribution is CocoaPods) and just built the application without changing the code.

When I build the iOS application after building the Android application (even if I run Android after iOS), it fails with a following error.

```
Gradle could not start your build.
> Could not create service of type ResourceSnapshotterCacheService using GradleUserHomeServices.createResourceSnapshotterCacheService().
   > Timeout waiting to lock file hash cache (/Users/<user-name>/.gradle/caches/6.7.1/fileHashes). It is currently in use by another Gradle instance.
     Owner PID: 57033
     Our PID: 57624
     Owner Operation: 
     Our operation: 
     Lock file: /Users/<user-name>/.gradle/caches/6.7.1/fileHashes/fileHashes.lock
```

If I kill the another Gradle process and delete the lock file, the build will succeed. But I can't do this every time.

I don't know what's wrong and differences from others.

BTW, I created the project that supports [improved Gradle task `embedAndSignAppleFrameworkForXcode`](https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2021/07/multiplatform-gradle-plugin-improved-for-connecting-kmm-modules/).

---

My environment is below...

- macOS Big Sur 11.4
- Android Studio 4.2.2
- Kotlin 1.5.21
- Kotlin Multiplatform Mobile 0.2.6 (202-1.5.10-release-894-IJ)-8
- Gradle 6.7.1
- AGP 4.2.2
- Java 11.0.8 2020-07-14 LTS
- Xcode: 12.5.1 (12E507)

Comment: JDK location was wrong. Need to set JAVA_HOME.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try updating `gradle` to `7.1.1` (latest version)

If this doesn't help, consider creating an issue on [jetbrains issue tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue), because this doesn't seems like a typical problem and may be solved much faster there

Comment: JDK location was wrong.
I should have noticed a warning in the event log at Android Studio.

I set Embedded JDK, but I need to set JAVA_HOME.
Not necessary to update gradle to latest.

Thanks for the advice!